# Oracle Apex, line break in Gantt Chart Row Label

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm very new to Oracle Apex and currently I want to use and customize Gantt charts. What I want to achieve it to show line breaks in the row-labels. Currently every newline character gets cut out and I am not sure where this happens and how I can prevent this.
The marked text contains newline characters. Don't be confused by the <br>, I just tests if this does the trick.

[image]

I just want to show more some information in the for each row. If there is another more elegant way, it would be very nice to give a tip.

**Update:**

I did some research and found a very nice example on a similar topic, in this case to create a custom tooltip https://youtu.be/2rZAIR_0tNg?t=2532.
I wanted to do the same thing for the row_axis label renderer, but nothing gets visualized.

The render function I use:

```
function custom_row_axis_label_renderer(data_context){
    var row_axis_label_elem = document.createElement("g");
    $("row_axis_label_elem").addClass("custom_row_axis_label");
    row_axis_label_elem.innerHTML = '<text font-size="14px">Hello World</text>';
    console.log(row_axis_label_elem);
    return row_axis_label_elem;
}
```

The rendered element kind of exists, but it's get the size 0x0 from somewhere.
[image]
[image]

Am I missing something here?

Regards,
Nik

Comment: I think labels of oJet components do not support html tags

Comment: You seem to be right there. I found a function to add a custom renderer, but this doesn't work for me yet (see Update of question)

Comment: I have the same in one of my apps where I use font apex icons in a label. It's doesn't work :)

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this?

Comment: @KoenLostrie I found a solution for my issue, see my answer. Maybe this could solve also the problem you had.

Comment: thanks ! I'll keep this in mind for future projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I found the solution on how to build a custom renderer. The main part I didn't new is that you NEED to pass x and y coordinates to have the new label to be rendered correctly. I found a proper example the the oracle forum, but unfortunately I can't find the link anymore to give credit to the original example.

Here is my code. It creates two text elements below each other to achieve a mocked line break and it adds a yellow icon. Of course you can use the data_context object to access the actual label. Add this part in the "Function and Global Variable Declaration
" part of your page:

```
custom_row_axis_label_renderer = function (data_context){
    var row_axis_label_elem = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g"); 
    var upper_text = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");        
    var lower_text = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");       
    var icon_node = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");     
   
    upper_text.textContent = "Hello";    
    upper_text.setAttribute("dominant-baseline","text-before-edge");    
    upper_text.setAttribute("class","oj-gantt-row-label");    
    upper_text.setAttribute("font-size","14px");    
    upper_text.setAttribute("text-anchor","end");    
    upper_text.setAttribute("x","220");   
    upper_text.setAttribute("y","5");
    
    lower_text.textContent = "World";    
    lower_text.setAttribute("dominant-baseline","text-before-edge");    
    lower_text.setAttribute("class","oj-gantt-row-label");    
    lower_text.setAttribute("font-size","14px");    
    lower_text.setAttribute("text-anchor","end");    
    lower_text.setAttribute("x","220");   
    lower_text.setAttribute("y","25");
    
    
    icon_node.setAttribute("cx","240");    
    icon_node.setAttribute("cy","25");    
    icon_node.setAttribute("r","8");    
    icon_node.setAttribute("class","u-color-7");
    
    row_axis_label_elem.appendChild(upper_text);  
    row_axis_label_elem.appendChild(lower_text); 
    row_axis_label_elem.appendChild(icon_node); 
    
    return row_axis_label_elem;
}
```

Also you need to set the renderer of the row-axis-label. I also made the rows and task a little bit bigger to have enough space for two lines of text in the label. Add this in the "JavaScript Initialization Code" in the attriutes of you chart:

```
function( options ){
    options.rowAxis.label = {renderer : custom_row_axis_label_renderer};
 
    options.rowDefaults = {height : 60};
    options.taskDefaults = {height: 40};

    return options;
}
```